# How to use Styled Components for a component passed as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have 3 components in 3 differents files :

```
//file1
const Icon1 = styled.div`
width: 10px;
`;
const Widget1 = () => <BaseWidget icon={<Icon1 />} />

//file2  
const Icon2 = styled.div`
width: 15px;
`;
const Widget2 = () => <BaseWidget icon={<Icon2 />} />

//file3
const Icon3 = styled.div`
width: 20px;
`;
const Widget3 = () => <BaseWidget icon={<Icon3 />} />
```

and my base widget :

```
//basewidget
const BaseWidget = (props) => <div>{props.icon}</div>
```

My question is : how can I add style to props.icon in basewidget ?
Can I create a styled component based on props.icon and add a common css property ?
If it's not possible what is the best solution ?

Thanks,
Jef

Comment: What is `props.icon`? It's not actually clear because what it looks like in the code is a string

Comment: props.icon is one of the components declared above : Icon1 or Icon2 or Icon3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing in `icon={<Icon2 />}` you are actually passing a JSX element, which cannot be styled from the other side with styled-components because it is not a component. To style a component, it needs to take the `className` as a prop. In this case, your best bet is to write a styled-component wrapper `dev` and let the styles cascade to your `{props.icon}`

But because you are not passing in any props to `Icon` you could easily pass in the component as a prop making it stylable.

```
<BaseWidget icon={Icon1} />
```

Where you are receiving it:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledIcon = styled.i``;

const BaseWidget = (props) => {
  const { Icon } = props.icon;
  return (
    <StyledIcon as={Icon} />
  );
}
```

[`as` Docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop)